# Suddenly the apk size increase from 24 mb to 88 mb

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I had used flutter build apk more than 20 times and it size was 24 mega byte
but now suddenly it is 88 mega byte in release mode
can anyone tell me why that happen

note : the assets file is 4.9 mega byte
note : i don't have any videos or gif in my app

Comment: Building bundle app? Try ``flutter clean`` before building the app bundle / apk

Comment: i want to build release apk , and yes i did flutter clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added any new dependencies since your last release build?

Comment: Yes , file picker - url_launcher - voice

Comment: flutter_sound this package is the reason for fat apk , after deleting it , the size return to 26 but i need this package

Comment: Cool ! Can you mark my answer as approved ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you built a universal APK. This type of APK contains all the files that are required for all types of CPU. This also makes the APK very large.

Try running `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. This will create a seperate APK for the different CPU types.

Comment: but at the morning i build the release apk with 24 mb  and it was no problem

Comment: @MariamYounes Have you tried "split-per-abi"? I can't imagine anything else causing such a huge size difference.

Comment: I tried it and the size become 38 and it is very big also